# Set sbt options in build.sbt

Tags: sbt

I'm working on an SBT project that has to be built with the options like:

```
-Xmx2G -Xss256M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

This means that every new developer has to read the readme and assign the options to `SBT_OPTS` in bash profile or put them in the `sbtopts` file. Similarly, this has to be configured on Jenkins and this applies to all the projects (so if someone wants to use `-XX:+UseG1GC` with other projects it becomes an issue). Is it possible to specify the required options in the build file itself? This seems logical to me, as the options are project-specific and without them, you cannot build the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `.sbtopts` file at the root of the build with contents:

```
-J-Xmx2G
-J-Xss256M
-J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that you can have per-project `sbtopts` file. I have one question which is a bit not aligned, but maybe you have an idea how to overcome that. I discovered that my Jenkins has `-XX:+UseG1GC` by default in the `JAVA_OPTS` variable. So when I add the `.sbtopts` the build fails with _Conflicting collector combinations in option list; please refer to the release notes for the combinations allowed
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit._ Is there a way to nicely overcome this?

Comment: Try adding `-XX:-UseG1GC` to disable G1GC.